# How to use IDroid ORM framework to access Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, frameworks, dao

How can i create table , insert records ,update records ,delete records, query records on Sqlite Database from IDroid Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all those dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.hadoopz:IConveyor:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.hadoopz:ITools:1.0.33'
implementation 'com.hadoopz:IProtocol:1.0.59'
```

add all class needed:

```
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.sql.annotation.MyColumn;
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.sql.annotation.MyId;
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.sql.annotation.MyTable;

  import com.hadoopz.MyDroidLib.orm.core.session.SerenaSession;
  import com.hadoopz.MyDroidLib.orm.dao.DaoBoss;
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.beans.MySqlCharSet;
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.sql.MySqlEngine;
  import com.mycomm.IProtocol.sql.annotation.UniversalDBColumType;
```

Create a java class as an indicator of the sqlite database table as below:

```
@MyTable(tableCharset = MySqlCharSet.TableCharSetUTF8,tableEngine = MySqlEngine.EngineInnoDB)
class UserTable{
    @MyId
    private long userId;
    @MyColumn(ColumnType = UniversalDBColumType.DBColumString)
    private String userEmail;
    @MyColumn(ColumnType = UniversalDBColumType.DBColumString)
    private String userPassword;
    @MyColumn(ColumnType = UniversalDBColumType.DBColumInt)
    private int age;
    @MyColumn(ColumnType = UniversalDBColumType.DBColumLong)
    private long dateOfBirth;

    public UserTable() {//make sure you have a default constructor
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(long dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

add a test method to communicate with Sqlite database:

```
private void DAOTest(){
    SerenaSession session = DaoBoss.getSqliteSession(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkTableExist(UserTable.class);//if the table does not exist ,then create the table automatically
    UserTable user = new UserTable();
    user.setUserEmail("294356967@qq.com");
    user.setUserPassword("myStrongPassword");
    user.setAge(100);
    session.save(user);//save user into database,then you will see this record in sqllite db file

    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setAge(120);
    session.update(user);//change the age to 120 when userId = 1(all other fields keep the same value)

    Object new_user = session.find(UserTable.class,1L); //find the record when recordid=1
    if(new_user instanceof UserTable){
        UserTable usr_ =  (UserTable)new_user;
        System.out.println("the user is:"+usr_);
    }

    session.delete(UserTable.class,1L);//delete the record from table when record id=1
}
```